# jquery find a div which does not have a span as the first child

Tags: jquery

The number of divs is variable, but they all share a parent container:

```
<div>
    <span><br/></span>
    Lorem Ipsum
</div>
<div>
    <!-- need a span here -->
    Lorem Ipsum
</div>
<div>
    <span><br/></span>
    Lorem Ipsum
</div>
<div>
    <!-- need a span here -->
    Lorem Ipsum
</div>
<div>
    <span><br/></span>
    Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

How do I prepend a `span` tag to all the divs which don't have one. All the spans will be the same, they just have a line break so later on I can call `text()` on the parent and those will be converted into `\n`'s so the grouped content will show up nicely in an email where `enctype="text/plain"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).children(':first').is('span');
}).prepend('<span><br/></span>');
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/snJhY/

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did a fiddle to show.

`$("div").not(":has(span)").addClass("red");​`

All you need to do is change the ending to `append("span")` instead of `addClass("red")`

It is short and sweet, and I believe it is pretty logical also. Find the div that does not have a span.

http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/zHdfL/

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this works, and will only look at the `span` as a first child:

```
$('div:not(:has(span:first-child))').prepend('<span><br /></span>');​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRLLt/1/). But it looks like @kwelch [beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9488164/74757). Beware that text nodes are not counted, so a `<span>` *after* your "Lorem Ipsum" text will still cause another `<span>` to be prepended.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want like this

```
$("div:not(:has(span))").prepend("<span><br/></span>");
```

Comment: I tested this and it added a span to each div. Since every div is not a span.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to all and then remove the duplicates:

```
$('div').prepend('<span><br></span>');
$('div span:first-child').nextAll().remove();​
```